# How to make relational Prisma query with multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, prisma

I'm a little confused on what options to pass in to `items.findMany` to achieve the particular result I'm looking for.

My DB Schema looks like this:

```
enum progress_status {
  validating
  valid
  invalid
}

model items {
  id               String
  item_name     String
  status           item_status  
}

model item_status {
  id            String        
  item_id       String
  status        progress_status
}
```

I'd like to query for all items where `item_name` starts with a certain value (For a search feature), and where its status is a certain status. So for example, get all items that start with `foo` and have a status of `valid`

So far I have the text query working with:

```
  const result = await client.items.findMany({
    where: {
      item_name: {
        startsWith: query,
      }
    },
    orderBy: {
      project_name: 'asc',
    }
  });
```

But I'm having trouble adding the condition for the status. I know I can include the status data with an `include` parameter, but I am uncertain how to additional filter results by status.